# Are you allowed to use a find_each query with an includes statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

example:

```
Foobar.joins(:baz).includes(:baz).count
=> 22926
Foobar.joins(:baz).includes(:baz).find_each.count
=> 998
Foobar.joins(:baz).find_each.count
=> 22926
```

The generated sql in the correct case (third) is several batches of sql that looks like:

```
SELECT  "foobar".* FROM "foobar" INNER JOIN "baz" ON 
"baz"."foobar_id" = "foobar"."id" ORDER BY "foobar"."id" ASC LIMIT $1
```

in the failing (second) case there is a single query that looks like:

```
SELECT  "foobar"."id" AS t0_r0
 "baz"."id" AS t1_r0
 "baz"."foobar_id" AS t1_r1
 FROM "foobar" INNER JOIN "baz" ON "baz"."foobar_id" = "foobar"."id" 
 ORDER BY "foobar"."id" ASC LIMIT $1
```

where all of the fields are listed as a different temporary variable (e.g. `t0_r0`) for the different columns on each table (in the actual query there are 37 split 30 on the first object, 7 on the second).

Is this a bug? are `includes` not allowed in a `find_each` query? Am I doing something wrong?

The relationship between `Foobar` and `Baz` is `Foobar` `has_one` `Baz` and `Baz` `belongs_to` `Foobar`.

Comment: What Rails version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Rails 5.0.2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This problem can happen if your `has_one` relationship isn't really `has_one`.

Say that your database doesn't have a unique index on the column `baz.foobar_id`.  Then you could accidentally end up with a situation like this where you have a Foobar record that is connected to more than one Baz record:

```
baz.id | baz.foobar_id
------   -------------
1        1
2        1
3        2
```

In this situation, the `joins` will return the combination of Foobar and Baz records:

```
Foobar.joins(:baz).count  # This would be 3
```

This also means that `find_each` with `join` would iterate 3 times and repeat one of the Foobar IDs:

```
Foobar.joins(:baz).find_each(batch_size: 2) { |f| puts f.id }
# SELECT  "foobar".* FROM "foobar" INNER JOIN "baz" ON... LIMIT 2
1
1
# SELECT  "foobar".* FROM "foobar" INNER JOIN "baz" ON... WHERE ("foobar"."id" > 1) ... LIMIT 2
2
```

Adding in `includes` means that Rails is going to try to consolidate the results back into a set of distinct Foobar records.  But this won't work with how `find_each` manages its batches:

```
Foobar.joins(:baz).includes(:baz).find_each(batch_size: 2) { |f| puts f.id }
# SELECT  "foobar"."id" AS t0_r0 ... LIMIT 2
1
```

And at this point `find_each` will [stop processing](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb#L232) because it has found an early batch is smaller than the batch size, so it thinks it is done:

```
# ActiveRecord::Batches#in_batches
break if ids.length < batch_limit
```

The default batch size for `find_each` is 1,000.  Your problem case returned 998 records.  That indicates that the first batch it loaded 998 unique Foobar IDs which is less than the batch size, and `find_each` thought it was done.  It probably loaded up 1,000 Baz records which were connected to 998 distinct Foobar records.

You may want to review your `baz` table to see if it has any duplicate entries.  You can do this with something like:

```
Baz.group(:foobar_id).having('count(*) > 1')
```

The best solution would be to use a unique index to avoid duplicates in the database and to enforce the `has_one` relationship.  An alternative would be to ensure you're getting a distinct set of Foobar records with something like:

```
Foobar.group(:id).joins(:baz).includes(:baz).count
Foobar.group(:id).joins(:baz).includes(:baz).find_each.count
Foobar.group(:id).joins(:baz).find_each.count
```